# Dynamic or conditional based Promise.all() and destructing

Tags: javascript, promise, destructuring

I want to get data from DB based on the boolean flag.

```
async function main() {
  let promises = [];

  if (false) {
    promises.push(Promise.resolve("highlights from DB"));
  }

  if (true) {
    promises.push(Promise.resolve("featured video from DB"));
  }

  if (true) {
    promises.push(Promise.resolve("categories from DB"));
  }

  const [highLightVideo, featuredVideo, categories] = await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log("highLightVideo: ", highLightVideo);
  console.log("featuredVideo: ", featuredVideo);
  console.log("categories: ", categories);
}

main();
```

**Above code output:**

```
highLightVideo:  featured video from DB
featuredVideo:  categories from DB
categories:  undefined
```

**Output I need:**

```
highLightVideo:  undefined
featuredVideo:  featured video from DB
categories:  categories from DB
```

Note: (Solution that won't work for me because of project structure)

- I cannot use `.then()` flow.
- I cannot return any custom value like this `promises.push(Promise.resolve({ msg: "highlights from DB", type: 'HIGHLIGHT' }));`

Comment: Obviously,. if you pass in an array of two promises, you will only be able to destructure `[0]` and `[1]`, which is "incorrect" (your words). However, you _can_ and _should_ add a `Promose.resolve( undefined )` or something for every one of the destructures you want to do to ensure three values come out. Personally, I find this a weird question. Like wondering why your sentences don't make sense when you drop random words in the middle. And whatever if returned doesn't matter, you can still do a check after the Promise.all to see if they returned, say, `null`, or maybe a `Symbol`

Comment: @somethinghere - doesn't even have to be a Promise that is pushed

Comment: @JaromandaX Promise all just does that? Cool, haven't really had to use it in that way but good to know. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just push a resolved promise of `undefined` for the things you don't care about, so the length of `promises` is always 3 and you can destructure it in a constant way:

```js
const undefinedPromise = Promise.resolve(undefined);

async function getThings(highlights, featured, categories) {
  const promises = [];

  if (highlights) {
    promises.push(Promise.resolve("highlights from DB"));
  } else {
    promises.push(undefinedPromise);
  }

  if (featured) {
    promises.push(Promise.resolve("featured video from DB"));
  } else {
    promises.push(undefinedPromise);
  }

  if (categories) {
    promises.push(Promise.resolve("categories from DB"));
  } else {
    promises.push(undefinedPromise);
  }
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

console.log(await getThings(true, false, true));
console.log(await getThings(false, true, true));
console.log(await getThings(true, true, true));
```

Comment: Ahhh!! Thanks @AKX. I didn't think that way, I think I need a coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve any static value with `Promise.all()`. In this option empty values will be equal `false`:

```js
function getThings(highlights, featured, categories) {
  return Promise.all([
    highlights && Promise.resolve("highlights from DB"),
    featured && Promise.resolve("featured video from DB"),
    categories && Promise.resolve("categories from DB")
  ]);
}

(async()=>{
console.log(await getThings(true, false, true));
console.log(await getThings(false, true, true));
console.log(await getThings(true, true, true));
})();
```

If you want exact `undefined`:

```js
function getThings(highlights, featured, categories) {
  return Promise.all([
    highlights ? Promise.resolve("highlights from DB") : undefined,
    featured ? Promise.resolve("featured video from DB") : undefined,
    categories ? Promise.resolve("categories from DB") : undefined
  ]);
}

(async()=>{
console.log(await getThings(true, false, true));
console.log(await getThings(false, true, true));
console.log(await getThings(true, true, true));
})();
```